# How to arrange files according to rename date?

Tags: rename

I tried more things Date modified,Date Accessed & Date created etc, but none arranges the files according to rename date.

How to arrange files according to rename date ?

Comment: Which OS are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Windows, and/or a Windows-compatible file system (say NTFS, or FAT):

> none arranges the files according to rename date

There is no "rename date" property for files, and renaming a file does not update its 'last modified' time stamp, only its 'last accessed' (which is updated simply because you accessed the file, not because you renamed it).

> How to arrange files according to rename date?

You can't (see above).

You'd have to modify the *contents* of the files, or make a new copy of the file, while renaming them for the modification/creation timestamps to be updated; and then sort by one of those.